# ASP.NET Core HttpContext.Response.StatusCode is 200 when exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an endpoint that throws exception.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api")]
public class LegacyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("endpoint")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Entitty>>> GetAll()
    {
        throw new Exception();
        return Ok(t.ToList());
    }
}
```

I have custom Http logging filter that looks like this

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Client.API.Extensions
{
    public class HttpLoggingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public HttpLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<HttpLoggingMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            finally
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(
                    "Request {method} {url} => {statusCode}",
                    context.Request?.Method,
                    context.Request?.Path.Value,
                    context.Response?.StatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I'm calling this endpoint, context.Response?.StatusCode is 200. Why?

However, Postman shows me that my request failed, I see en error itself, therefore everything looks normal. Although logs contain 200 status code message, not the 500.

Edit: here is my startup (some parts are removed).

```
namespace Client.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UsePathBase(new PathString(basePath));
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseMiddleware<HttpLoggingMiddleware>();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show your middleware configuration (Startup.Configure method). Most likely, your middleware is incorrectly registered

Comment: What is the purpose of all this weird code? What is your goal? To find a bug in MVC?

Comment: @Serge I'm implementing http logging for out service. This code is just an example to show that my code isn't working is it's intended and I don't know why

Comment: @osynavets It is http client stuff, but you even didn' t post http client request

Comment: @osynavets I tested the code , it returns 500 error. This is why I would like to see your httpclient code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch the Exception, You need to use specific middleware--`app.UseExceptionHandler();`, So firstly I use this middleware to set the log.

The code is:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(
  appErr =>
  {
    appErr.Run(
    async context =>
    {
      logger.LogInformation(
      "Request {method} {url} => {statusCode}",
       context.Request?.Method,
       context.Request?.Path.Value,
       context.Response?.StatusCode);
    });
});
```

But There is a problem, This middleware can only catch the exception, So when the response code is not `500`, The request will not get into this middleware.

Finally I changed a method, I use `try/catch` to catch the exception and set the `StatusCode` by myself and it success. The code show as below：

```
public class HttpLoggingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly ILogger<HttpLoggingMiddleware> _logger;

        public HttpLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next,ILogger<HttpLoggingMiddleware> logger)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //catch the Exception and set the StatusCode 
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }
            finally
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(
                    "Request {method} {url} => {statusCode}",
                    context.Request?.Method,
                    context.Request?.Path.Value,
                    context.Response?.StatusCode);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: This line of code makes a difference. 
catch (Exception)
{
    //catch the Exception and set the StatusCode 
    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}
For some reason even when exception occurs status code is still 200